# Python PEP8: Ignore single import on multi-line import

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I have the following import in my python code:

```
from apps.balance.models import BLOCKED, CREDIT, TRIAL, TrialAlert
```

But PEP8/flake8 tells my that `TrialAlert` is not used. In the code itself, it really isn't used, but I do use it in MyPy annotations, so I've trying to add a "noqa" **just for it**, without success. If I change the line to

```
from apps.balance.models import BLOCKED, CREDIT, TRIAL, TrialAlert   # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import
```

It works! But then I believe it will ignore the other imports, which are used. I also tried

```
from apps.balance.models import (                                                                                       
    BLOCKED,                                                                                                            
    CREDIT,                                                                                                             
    TRIAL,                                                                                                              
    TrialAlert   # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import                                                                 
)
```

But it also didn't worked. Can anybody tell me how to ignore **just** that last import?

Comment: I do not think it's possible due to the way the interpreter/grammar works. Your best bet would probably be to split it to 2 different imports: `from apps.balance.models import BLOCKED, CREDIT, TRIAL ; from apps.balance.models import TrialAlert   # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import
`, unfortunately violating DYI.

Comment: Side note: PEP8 changed its name to [pycodestyle](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle) by [request of Guido Van Rossum](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/466) about three ago.

Comment: I meant "unfortunately violating *DRY*", of course....

Comment: You should never import individual symbols from a module. Instead `from apps.balance import models` then use `models. BLOCKED`, etc.

Comment: @KurtisRader Can you please supply more details on why we should never import individual constants, methods or class, and instead just import the whole file?

Comment: Kurtis' assertion is a matter of opinion. PEP8 does not have an opinion on this. Different larger companies (e.g., Google) and projects (e.g., OpenStack) have this as a rule but allow for exceptions. Even Google's style guide allows for type anontations to be imported instead of a module.

Comment: Ian is correct that my statement is a contentious recommendation. I learned to prefer it as a Google SWE: http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html. When I compare code that adheres to that recommendation to that which doesn't I find the latter distinctly harder to understand.

Comment: If you upgrade flake8 to 3.7.x imports for type comments are now considered "used" and won't be flagged by pyflakes / flake8

Answer (score 1):

You must add:

```
from apps.balance.models import ( # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import                                                                               
    BLOCKED,                                                                                                           
    CREDIT,                                                                                                             
    TRIAL,                                                                                                              
    TrialAlert                                                                 
)
```

To disable the flake8 warning:

```
from apps.balance.models import ( # noqa F401                                                                              
    BLOCKED,                                                                                                           
    CREDIT,                                                                                                             
    TRIAL,                                                                                                              
    TrialAlert                                                                 
)
```